# How do you break down <10% H202 and <10% NAOH

Tags: organic-chemistry

I have a waste discharge that will generate 40 litres of <10% H202 and <10% NAOH at separate times.  I have authorization to discharge to the sanitary drain, but I am concerned about degradation of the cast iron sanitary line.  What is the best way to break down these two compounds?

Comment: I think you shouldn't be concerned unless this will be a recurrent task.

Answer (score 0):

I would dilute the hydrogen peroxide in a large open container with water. Then, add a piece of iron metal that was previously heated in air. The $\ce{FeO}$ coating will cause the breakdown of the $\ce{H2O2}$ (reference, see [this work](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/es970648k) and also [Wikipedia comments here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_peroxide)).

An alternate path that liberates oxygen is via the addition of a dilute solution of Sodium hypochlorite ($\ce{NaOCl}$) the active ingredient in chlorine bleach. The residual product is salt water.

Also, to address the safe disposal of the caustic Sodium hydroxide, I would similarly dilute the $\ce{NaOH}$. Proceed to add a convenient acid source, say vinegar or lemon juice to effect a safe neutralization.

Comment: Apparently it is not $\ce{FeO}$ that catalyzes decomposition of $\ce{H2O2}$. It is either $\ce{Fe3O4}$ or goethite $\ce{FeO(OH)}$

Comment: @Maurice: Any ferrous salt, as noted in the Wikipedia reference, will work. It is Fenton chemistry, see https://www.pnas.org/content/111/2/623. The particular compounds you noted have mixed oxidation states of iron including Fe(II).

Comment: I would add further that the particular mixed iron salts you mentioned are especially effective (as in energetic). No likely the best choice here, especially if the H2O2 is not well diluted, but thanks for the comment as it does highlight a potential safety issue.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to store one waste stream until the other is generated, simply mixing the two waste streams might be effective. Peroxide solutions are usually maintained at acidic pH because the hydroperoxy anion is unstable and breaks down to $\ce{HO-}$ and $\ce{O2}$ through the reaction

$$\ce{H-O-O- + H-O-O-H -> H2O + O2 + HO-}$$

So adding base to your peroxide solution until the pH is high enough to generate hydroperoxy anions will result in their destruction (and neutralize the base you are adding). NOTE THAT THIS REACTION SHOULD BE DONE SLOWLY AND NOT WITH HIGHER CONCENTRATIONS OF PEROXIDE, as a fair amount of heat is generated. The vessels must be vented as well, as the gas production can build up pressure rapidly. But with your low concentrations, the safety hazards are fairly low.

If you still have NaOH solution leftover or the mix is too high pH, simply bubbling carbon dioxide or adding solid sodium bicarbonate will neutralize it.

You can find more about the above reaction [here](https://www.fpl.fs.fed.us/documnts/pdf2013/fpl_2013_hart001.pdf)

Comment: My experience with dilute 3% H2O2 (which is normally acidic for stability reasons) to which is added some NaHCO3 results in a mild reaction. The H2O2 now, however, per testing with NaOCl, displays a much-reduced shelf-life. So, this is an alternate safe path as suggested by Andrew (namely, raising the pH of a diluted H2O2 solution).